nodejs canvas works fine in mac os but in aws ec2 ubuntu renders incorrectly
I have set up Docker and implemented Node.js Canvas to render an image and font. It generates fine when running locally using Docker, but on AWS EC2, when running in Docker, the canvas image is being generated differently.
This is the code
export async function generateEmailSignature(id: string, folder: string, uploadKey: string, logoImagePath: string, qrImagePath: string, name: string) {
    try {
        registerFont('./src/common/open-sans-condensed/OpenSans-Light.ttf', { family: 'Open Sans Condensed', weight: 'light' });
        registerFont('./src/common/open-sans-condensed/OpenSans-Bold.ttf', { family: 'Open Sans Condensed', weight: 'bold' });

        const dpi = process.platform === 'darwin' ? 2 : 1;  // Use a higher DPI for high-res displays

        // The requested dimensions in pixels
        const width = 544; // Width in pixels
        const height = 237; // Height in pixels

        // Create a canvas with the specified dimensions
        const canvas = createCanvas(width * dpi, height * dpi);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.scale(dpi, dpi);

        // Background color
        ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFAFF'; // Light background color
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        // QR image
        const qrMinHeight = 200;
        const qrMinWidth = 200;

        // logo image
        const logoMinHeight = 55;
        const logoMinWidth = 55;

        // Draw border
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#092B4A'; // Blue border
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        ctx.strokeRect(2, 2, width - 4, height - 4);

        // Add title text
        const titleTextPositionX = 30;
        const titleTextPositionY = 80;

        // Set the font style for the "Click" part
        ctx.font = 'bold 26pt "Open Sans Condensed"'; // Set font size and family
        ctx.fillStyle = '#0000ff'; // Set text color to blue

        // Draw "Click" with blue and underlined
        ctx.fillText("Click", titleTextPositionX, titleTextPositionY);

        const textWidth = ctx.measureText("Click").width;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(titleTextPositionX, titleTextPositionY + 2); // Starting position of underline
        ctx.lineTo(titleTextPositionX + textWidth, titleTextPositionY + 2); // Ending position of underline
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#0000ff'; // Set underline color to blue
        ctx.lineWidth = 2; // Set the underline thickness
        ctx.stroke();

        // Add "or Scan to" in bold
        ctx.fillStyle = '#092B4A'; // Navy blue
        ctx.font = 'bold 26pt "Open Sans Condensed"';
        ctx.fillText('or Scan to', titleTextPositionX + textWidth + 10, titleTextPositionY);
        
        const titleX = 68;
        const titleY = 122;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#092B4A';
        ctx.font = 'bold 28pt "Open Sans Condensed"';
        ctx.fillText('Helloo', titleX, titleY);

        // Load and draw the logo
        const logoPath = logoImagePath;
        const logo = await loadImage(logoPath);

        // logo position
        const positionX = 26;
        const positionY = 155;

        ctx.drawImage(logo, positionX, positionY, logoMinWidth, logoMinHeight); // Position and resize logo


        const produlySuppportedTextPositionX = 86;
        const produlySuppportedTextPositionY = 180;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#092B4A';
        ctx.font = 'Light 12pt "Open Sans Condensed"';
        ctx.fillText('by', produlySuppportedTextPositionX, produlySuppportedTextPositionY);

        const nameTextPositionX = 86;
        const nameTextPositionY = 200;

        ctx.fillText(name, nameTextPositionX, nameTextPositionY);

        // Generate a QR code
        const qrCodePositionX = 315;
        const qrCodePositionY = 23;

        const qrCodeImage = await loadImage(qrImagePath);
        ctx.drawImage(qrCodeImage, qrCodePositionX, qrCodePositionY, qrMinWidth, qrMinHeight); // Position and resize QR code

        // Set the stroke color and line width
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#092B4A';  // Blue color for the border
        ctx.lineWidth = 8;         // 4pt line width

        // Draw the curved border around the QR code
        ctx.beginPath();
        const borderRadius = 5;  // Radius for the curved corners

        // Top-left corner
        ctx.moveTo(qrCodePositionX + borderRadius, qrCodePositionY);

        // Top side
        ctx.arcTo(qrCodePositionX + qrMinWidth, qrCodePositionY, qrCodePositionX + qrMinWidth, qrCodePositionY + qrMinHeight, borderRadius);

        // Right side
        ctx.arcTo(qrCodePositionX + qrMinWidth, qrCodePositionY + qrMinHeight, qrCodePositionX, qrCodePositionY + qrMinHeight, borderRadius);

        // Bottom side
        ctx.arcTo(qrCodePositionX, qrCodePositionY + qrMinHeight, qrCodePositionX, qrCodePositionY, borderRadius);

        // Left side (closing the loop)
        ctx.arcTo(qrCodePositionX, qrCodePositionY, qrCodePositionX + qrMinWidth, qrCodePositionY, borderRadius);

        // Complete the path and draw
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();


        // Add footer copyright text
        // Set up the context for drawing
        const copyrightTextPositionX = 532;
        const copyrightTextPositionY = 222;

        ctx.fillStyle = '#092B4A';
        ctx.font = 'Light 7.5pt "Open Sans Condensed"';

        // Rotate the context for vertical text
        ctx.save();  // Save the current context state
        ctx.translate(copyrightTextPositionX, copyrightTextPositionY);  // Move the origin to where you want the vertical text
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);  // Rotate the context 90 degrees counterclockwise

        // Draw the copyright symbol
        ctx.fillText('Copyright', 0, 0);  // Draw at the new origin

        ctx.restore();  // Restore the context to its original state

        // Save the generated image
        const fileName = `emailBanner.png`;
        const filePath = `assets/emailBanner/${fileName}`;
        const folderName = `assets/emailBanner`;

        const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
        await fs.writeFile(fileName, buffer);
        console.log('Email banner created');

        return;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
}


differently how?

You are doing a lot in that code!! custom fonts, drawing lines, adding text, drawing images ... Please reduce the example to something minimal to reproduce the issue, Help us help you.
